# JNA with Windows DLL, callback function pointer with structure pointer, invalid memory access

Tags: java, c++, dll, dllimport, jna

My problem is that I am trying to connect a Windows DLL to my Java program via JNA and I am getting an invalid memory access error that I can't figure out.

I have a Windows (Vista 32 bit) DLL that defines a couple of functions as shown below. I know this works fine because I wrote a simple test program in Visual Studio 2008 that loads the DLL and runs the functions. The header of the DLL is as follows:

```
typedef struct info_struct
{
    char szSeries[12];
    char szSerialNO[48];
    unsigned int dwDeviceType;
    int iResult;
    unsigned char byIPv6MaskLen;       
    unsigned short wHttpPort;
    unsigned char byRes[15];   
} tMyCallbackInfo;

// Interface
typedef void (__stdcall *PMY_CALLBACK)(const tMyCallbackInfo; *lpCallbackInfo, void *pUserData);
extern "C"__declspec(dllimport) int __stdcall MYAPI_Start(PMY_CALLBACK pMyCallBack, int bInfo = 0, void* pUserData = NULL);
extern "C"__declspec(dllimport) int __stdcall MYAPI_Stop(void);
```

(This is a simplified version of the actual code, showing the main features). Note that the header defines a callback function pointer and passes that into a function MYAPI_Start, and the function pointer takes a pointer to a struct as an argument. Also note that the C++ code uses default argument values in that function (a C++ language feature, not a C language feature).

My program in Java is this:

```
// 
// MyProg.java

package com.whatever.myprog;

import com.sun.jna.*;
import com.sun.jna.win32.*;

public class MyProg {

    public MyProg() {
    }

    public void execute() {
        int ret=0;

        MyLibrary mylib = (MyLibrary)Native.loadLibrary("mydll", MyLibrary.class);
        MyCallbackInterface callbackObj = new MyCallbackImpl();

        System.out.println("Before MYAPI_Start");
        ret=mylib.MYAPI_Start(callbackObj , 0, Pointer.NULL);
        System.out.println("After MYAPI_Start, ret is "+ret);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            MyProg instance=new MyProg();
            instance.execute();
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
            System.out.println("Exception" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

This just loads the "mydll.dll" library and calls the function MYAPI_Start. The MyLibrary class is defined like this:

```
///////////////////////////////////////
// MyLibrary
///////////////////////////////////////

package com.whatever.myprog;

import com.sun.jna.*;
import com.sun.jna.win32.*;


public interface MyLibrary extends Library, StdCallLibrary  {

    public int MYAPI_Start(MyCallbackInterface pMyCallBack, int bInfo, Pointer pUserData);
    public int MYAPI_Stop();

}
```

MyCallbackInterface is defined like this:

```
///////////////////////////////////////
// MyCallbackInterface 
///////////////////////////////////////

package com.whatever.myprog;

import com.sun.jna.*;
import com.sun.jna.win32.*;


public interface MyCallbackInterface extends Callback, StdCallLibrary.StdCallCallback {
    void invoke(MyCallbackInfoStruct lpCallbackInfo, Pointer pUserData);
}
```

and the implementation is defined like this:

```
///////////////////////////////////////
// MyCallbackImpl 
///////////////////////////////////////

package com.whatever.myprog;

import com.sun.jna.*;

//
// define an implementation of the callback interface
//
public class MyCallbackImpl implements MyCallbackInterface {
    @Override
    public void invoke(MyCallbackInfoStruct lpCallbackInfo, Pointer pUserData) {
        System.out.println("Called invoke in MyCallbackImpl ");
    }
}
```

Finally the structure MyCallbackInfoStruct (needed by the function pointer) is defined like this:

```
///////////////////////////////////////
// MyCallbackInfoStruct
///////////////////////////////////////

package com.whatever.myprog;

import java.util.*;
import com.sun.jna.*;

public class MyCallbackInfoStruct extends Structure {

    public byte[] szSeries=new byte[12];
    public byte[] szSerialNO=new byte[48];
    public int dwDeviceType;
    public int iResult;
    public byte byIPv6MaskLen;
    public short wHttpPort;
    public byte[] byRes=new byte[15];

    @Override
    protected List getFieldOrder() {
         return Arrays.asList("szSeries","szSerialNO","dwDeviceType","iResult",
                              "byIPv6MaskLen","wHttpPort","byRes");
    }; 
}
```

This class should model the header file mydll.h correctly. It looks to me like I'm doing everything right according to the JNA docs, but I still get an invalid memory access error inside the call to MYAPI_Start. Is there some windows interface in com.sun.jna.win32 that I am not using properly? What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:
Here is a JPG of the stack trace:
[image]

Comment: Does `Structure.size()` return the same value as `sizeof(struct info_struct)`?

Comment: You should keep a reference to your callback object until you're certain the native code can no longer access it.  An aggressive GC might get rid of yours immediately after the call to `MyAPI_Start()`.

Comment: The sizes are indeed the same. And I have a reference to the callback object, but this is not the problem. The crash is inside MYAPI_Start(), not after it returns.

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace?

Comment: See stack trace in update above. SADP_Start_V30() is the real name of the function I was calling MYAPI_Start()

Comment: Turn off JNA protected mode (`Native.setProtected(false)`) and see what the JVM crash dump reports.  That should indicate how far down (if at all) you are in the native stack.  It appears you're not even making it into the callback code (assuming your native Start method calls it directly), otherwise you'd see some callback stack frames.