# Pointer to a function in java

Tags: java, dll, callback, jna

I have a dynamic link library (DLL) written in c++. In my DLL I have a function like this:

```cpp
void set_event_callback(EVENT_CALLBACK callback_fcn);
```

where `EVENT_CALLBACK` is a function pointer like this:

```cpp
void (*EVENT_CALLBACK)(int event_type, byte param1, int param2);
```

I use my DLL in other languages. For example, in C# I call `set_event_callback` like this:

```cs
public delegate void EVENT_CALLBACK(int event_type, byte param1, int param2);
EVENT_CALLBACK HandleEventsDelegate = null;
HandleEventsDelegate = new EVENT_CALLBACK(HandleEvents);
set_event_callback(HandleEventsDelegate);
```

where `HandleEvents` is a function like this:

```cs
protected void HandleANPREvents(int event_type, byte param1, int param2){ ... }
```

Now, I want to use my DLL in Java. I'm using JNA to call native code in my java project. I couldn't find function pointers in Java.

How can I call `set_event_callback` in Java and pass a function to my DLL?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35687695/jna-with-windows-dll-callback-function-pointer-with-structure-pointer-invalid looks a bit related.

Comment: My JNA is a bit rusty, but basically, you need to define a functional interface which extends `com.sun.jna.Callback` (for Windows, you probably need to extend `com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary.StdCallCallback` instead, but this depends on the call type). The functional interface must define a single method with the correct signature to match the callback (in your case, probably `void callback(int, byte, int)`). The method that expects the callback will need to accept that interface. The actual implementation of a callback needs to implement the interface.

Comment: See also [Callbacks, Function Pointers and Closures](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/CallbacksAndClosures.md)

Comment: Thank you  Mark Rotteveel. I will try to implement  it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72363774/pointer-to-a-function-in-java#comment127860410_72363774) by @Mark-Rotteveel states, you should define a functional interface with a single method matching the callback.  It could look something like this:

```java
// Extend StdCallLibrary if library is __stdcall
public interface YourDLL extends Library {
    YourDLL INSTANCE = // insert library loading code here

    // Define the callback
    // Extend StdCallCallback if library is __stdcall
    interface HandleANPREvents extends Callback {
        // the function name doesn't matter
        void invoke(int event_type, byte param1, int param2);
    }

    // Define the function using the callback
    void set_event_callback(HandleANPREvents callback_fcn);
}
```

You can then refer to `set_event_callback()` in your code.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HandleANPREvents fn = new HandleANPREvents() {
        @Override
        void invoke(int event_type, byte param1, int param2) {
            // implementation here
        }
    };
    YourDLL.INSTANCE.set_event_callback(fn);
}
```